# change names of every file in the directory via bash

Tags: bash, image

Look, I've got a directory full of images with various random names.

I'd like to have a script which will change all of the images names to
IMG_(and a random number from lets say 100 to 90000 here).

if there's such possibility i'd like to have it written in bash, because I will work with those images on a debian machine.

But every other solution you propose will be as much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does the number need to be random?  If you have random numbering instead of sequential numbering, you'll need to be able to generate unique "random" numbers, more akin to a shuffle algorithm.

Comment: in my case, these numbers need to be random, i guess that if I'll have, lets say 100 images in my directory and I will choose range of the numbers from 100 to 90000, the chance for number to be repeated is quite small isn't it? I just need to know how to define such variable in bash at the start of my script which will give me the random number.

Comment: There is absolutely no guarantee that you won't have collisions, regardless of how small you think the chance is.  And when you do, you need to have a solution.  If you're dumb about it you can end up overwriting another file and lose data.  You might consider using Python for this instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/bash

for img in `ls directory`;
do
    mv $img /samedirectory/newname
done;
```

newname here in your case is IMG_$num
try to inc $num for each image ...

Comment: is there a way to make a variable at first named $num which will contain random number from 100 to 999999?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

for img in dir/* ; do
    mv "$img" "/path/to/target/dir/newname_$RANDOM
done
```

That way you can get a random number between 0 and 32767. But as already mentioned in the comments, there is absolutely no guarantee that it will be collision free. Relies on `bash`, so for that it is possible that it wont work in other shells.

If you want to specify a greater range my suggestion is

```
randNumber=$((($RANDOM$RANDOM % $upperBorder) + $lowerBorder))
```